# Php _gettext output javascript code

Tags: javascript, php

I have php code

```
exitWithErrorPage(_gettext('error#1').'<script">do_something()</script>');
```

When error come out, javascript function 'do_something()' should work, but it's didn't.
Is it possible?

Comment: Depends. Does `exitWithErrorPage` work? Is `do_something()` defined before calling?

Comment: >Does `exitWithErrorPage` work? Yes, it works. 'do_something()' defined, sure

Comment: you have a double quote in script tag - <script">, maybe that's the problem?

Answer (score 2):

From what I see this should work correctly, as expected.
The only wrong thing is the double quote in your script tag. Assuming this is how you were running it, it may be interpreted as a closing double quote for another html tag and throw an error in the browser.

Try like this, see if it will work.

```
exitWithErrorPage(_gettext('error#1').'<script>do_something()</script>');
```